# React app not loading images and not working on GitHub Pages deployment

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, repo

I have a React app that works fine when running locally using npm start. However, when I deploy the app to GitHub Pages, it does not load, and the images are not being displayed.

Here's what I have tried so far:

Added "homepage": "https://lwilliams002.github.io/Stockboard/" to package.json.

Changed the import statement for the image in the component to import userImage from 'assets/user.jpg'; and used it in JSX like .

Moved the images to the public folder and used the following code in JSX to display the image: .

I have two package.json files, one in the root folder and another in the src folder. I merged the dependencies into one package.json file in the root folder and removed the other one.

Updated the build and deploy scripts in package.json:

json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

Changed the import statement for createRoot to import it from 'react-dom/client' instead of 'react-dom'.
Despite all these attempts, the app is still not working correctly on GitHub Pages, and the images are not being displayed.

Can anyone suggest what else I can do to resolve this issue?
https://github.com/Lwilliams002/Stockboard

Comment: Have you followed any tutorial, like [this one](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)? Did you install and configure the `gh-pages` plugin?

Comment: @ewerspej Here's what I have done so far:

I installed gh-pages : npm install gh-pages --save-dev then added the following scripts to my package.json file:

  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"

Updated the homepage field in my package.json:
"homepage": "https://lwilliams002.github.io/Stockboard/"

Ran npm run deploy to deploy the application. Despite following these steps, I am still facing issues with my GitHub Pages deployment. The application works fine locally but not on github pages